# Unable to understand "Sign in your user with Credential Manager" tutorial from developer.android.com

Tags: java, android

My goal is to use passkeys on Android and I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/passkeys) but the following code snippet is unclear:

```
// Retrieves the user's saved password for your app from their
// password provider.
GetPasswordOption getPasswordOption = new GetPasswordOption();

// Get passkeys from the user's public key credential provider.
GetPublicKeyCredentialOption getPublicKeyCredentialOption =
        new GetPublicKeyCredentialOption(requestJson, preferImmediatelyAvailableCredentials);
```

What should be in the `requestJson` String?

The article mentions *an example of how to format the JSON request*:

```
{
  "challenge": "T1xCsnxM2DNL2KdK5CLa6fMhD7OBqho6syzInk_n-Uo",
  "allowCredentials": [],
  "timeout": 1800000,
  "userVerification": "required",
  "rpId": "credential-manager-app-test.glitch.me"
}
```

But it's not clear how to generate the `challenge` and what to put in `rpId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, thanks to ChatGPT 4.

The `"challenge"` and `"rpId"` are part of the WebAuthn protocol, which is used for public key-based authentication. Here's what they mean:

1. `"challenge"`: This is a randomly generated value that is created by the relying party (in this case, your app) and sent to the authenticator (the user's device or security key). The challenge is signed by the authenticator and sent back to the relying party, who can then verify the signature to ensure the authenticity of the response. This prevents replay attacks, where an attacker might try to re-use a previous authentication response. To generate the challenge, you would typically use a secure random number generator to create a binary value, then encode it as a URL-safe base64 string.
2. `"rpId"`: This stands for Relying Party Identifier. It's essentially a way to identify your app to the authenticator. For web-based apps, it's typically the domain name of the site. For Android apps using WebAuthn, it's suggested to use a reverse-domain-name string, similar to the applicationId of your app. You can refer to your app's package name.

So, in Java, you might generate the `"challenge"` and set the `"rpId"` as follows:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] challenge = new byte[32]; // Use 32 bytes for the challenge
random.nextBytes(challenge);

// Encode the challenge as a URL-safe base64 string
String challengeBase64 = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(challenge);

// Set the rpId to your app's reverse domain name identifier
String rpId = "com.example.myapp";

// Now you can use these values to create the JSON request
JsonObject requestJson = Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("challenge", challengeBase64)
    .add("rpId", rpId)
    // Add any other parameters required by the GetPublicKeyCredentialOption constructor
    .build();
```

Please note: This example uses the `java.util.Base64` class for base64 encoding and the `javax.json.Json` class for JSON creation, which are both included in standard Java SE. If you're using Android or a different platform, you may need to use different classes for these purposes.

Also, while the example above does not include a timeout or userVerification setting, you may want to include those depending on your use case. The WebAuthn specification provides more information on these and other options.